# How to handle multiple if else conditions properly?

Tags: swift

I have three conditions:

1. Both `data.weight` and `myoutput` are `nil`
2. `myoutput` has no value
3. `data.weight` and `myoutput` both have a value

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super .viewWillAppear(animated)
       self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

       let myOutput = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "height")
       let dateFormator = DateFormatter()
       dateFormator.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
       let data = WeightTracker.mr_findFirst(with: NSPredicate(format: "date == %@", dateFormator.string(from: Date()))) as? WeightTracker

       if myOutput == nil && data?.weight == nil {
           bmiLabel.text = "--"
       } else if myOutput == nil && data?.weight != nil {
           bmiLabel.text = "--"
       } else {
           let dateFormator = DateFormatter()
           dateFormator.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
           if let data = WeightTracker.mr_findFirst(with: NSPredicate(format: "date == %@", dateFormator.string(from: Date()))) as? WeightTracker {
               let myOutput: AnyObject? = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "height") as AnyObject
               var sum = (myOutput as! NSString).doubleValue / 1000
               let total1 = sum * sum
               let total = Double(Int(data.weight!)!) / total1
               let dye = total/100.00
               bmiLabel.text = String(dye)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The sum should only be calculated for the third condition. What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: In your question, if `myOutput` **is not nil**  and if `data` **is nil** then it will go inside last else part and in `let total = Double(Int(data.weight!)!) / total1` you are _force-unwrapping_ `data` which will *result in crash*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if let myOutput = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "height") as? NSString , let weight = data?.weight {
    let dateFormator = DateFormatter()
    dateFormator.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    if let data = WeightTracker.mr_findFirst(with: NSPredicate(format: "date == %@", dateFormator.string(from: Date()))) as? WeightTracker{
        var sum = myOutput.doubleValue   / 1000
        let total1 = sum * sum
        let total = Double(Int(weight)!) / total1
        let dye = total/100.00

        bmiLabel.text = String(dye)
    }
} else {
    bmiLabel.text = "--"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you go the other way around

```
if myOutput != nil && data?.weight != nil {
    // Your logic here
}
else {
    bmiLabel.text = "--"
}
```

Or maybe replacing `if` with `if-let` altogether to provide safe unwrapping and to get rid of *optional chaining* and/or *force unwrapping*

```
if let myOutput = myOutput, let weight = data?.weight {
    // Your logic here
}
else {
    bmiLabel.text = "--"
}
```

Or if you want to provide *early escape* , then you can even use `guard-let`

```
guard let myOutputUnwrapped = myOutput, let weight = data?.weight else {
    bmiLabel.text = "--"
    return 
}

    /* Your logic here */
```

The advantages of `if-let` and `guard-let` is that you already get an unwrapped value to work with so you don't have to worry about `!` and `?` with variables.